# Firebase observer still gets values even after removeObserver

Tags: firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having a Firebase Handle like this:

```
private var typeIndicatorHandle: DatabaseHandle?
self.typeIndicatorHandle = self.dbRef.child("chats").child(chatId).child("typingIndicator").queryOrderedByValue().queryEqual(toValue: true).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            print("new value")
        })
```

somewhere else I do this:

```
if let typeIndicatorHandle = self.typeIndicatorHandle {
        self.dbRef.removeObserver(withHandle: typeIndicatorHandle)
    }
```

Now the problem is the observer still gets new values. How is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the observer on original children where you attached it.

For Example:

```
 private var typeIndicatorHandle: DatabaseHandle?
    private var dbRef:DatabaseReference?
self.childRef= self.dbRef.child("chats").child(chatId).child("typingIndicator").queryOrderedByValue().queryEqual(toValue: true)

    self.typeIndicatorHandle = childRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                print("new value")
            })
```

To Remove the listener:

```
if let typeIndicatorHandle = self.typeIndicatorHandle {
       self.childRef.removeObserver(withHandle: typeIndicatorHandle)
    }
```

Sorry for my bad syntax. I don't know swift that much in case of any correctness correct it.

But you need to remove the listener on the `DatabaseReference` on which you have added `listener`.